# Has anyone noticed that $G \times K\approx \frac{3}{5}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gravity, mass

I have noticed that $$G \times K\approx \frac{3}{5}$$ Where $G$ is the [universal gravitational constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) and $K$ is [Coulomb's constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law).

Moreover, the approximation is so good that, taking into account that $G$ has a relative standard uncertainty of $2.2 \times 10^{-5}$, one can even postulate that $$G \times K=\frac{3}{5}$$
As we have that $K=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$, where $\epsilon_0$ is the [electric vacuum permitivity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity), it can then be postulated that $$G=\frac{12\pi\epsilon_0}{5}$$

I would appreciate your comments and thoughts over the possible implications of the above, as well as suggestions on further steps to check the validity of my postulates. For me, it seems worthy to explore further this relationship, so I will appreciate your counsel for submitting a proper paper on the subject if you think that it is interesting and relevant enough for it.

Isn't it like "magic" that each of both constants is approximately the reciprocal of the other one? I guess there could be very deeps physics behind this relationship.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens if you use different units? (For example rationalized Gaussian units intead of Coulombs and Kilograms).

Comment: Coulomb’s constant is usually written as $k_e$ (as in the Wikipedia article you linked to) and not $K$.

Comment: *check the validity of my postulates* What postulates? You took well-established values for two physical constants *and then just dropped their units*, which is invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $ G/(4\pi\epsilon_0)$ is not dimensionless, then its approximate value of 3/5 m$^6$ s$^{-4}$ C$^{-2}$ in SI units is of no significance and depends on the chosen definitions of the metre, Coulomb and second.